# How should I handle vinyl siding when intersecting new walls?

Tags: outdoor, porch

I live in Ontario and am looking to close in an existing covered porch.
Naturally, I'll be building frames for doors and windows. How do you attach the frame to the house? I have vinyl siding. Would you use pressure-treated wood for this project? Is there a better product out there?

[image]

Comment: Are you looking to have an enclosed porch or are you trying to make this living space?

Comment: Enclosed porch. Something we can use during summer, spring and fall.

Answer (score 5):

To do the job correctly, you cut out and re-trim the vinyl siding so that the porch wall framing can be nailed or screwed directly to the house wall, with fasteners going into the framing of the house wall.

You *may* also choose to change out the vinyl siding for something else on what's now the inside wall of the porch, no longer directly exposed to the weather.